# Replace values in each Sheet in a Workbook using values from a Table

Tags: excel, vba, translation

Greeting!

I have a VBA that is in a Workbook with a Table containing strings for replacement. The VBA logic do the following:
Read files in folder
Create a separate process
Open a file from the folder in that separate process
In "Main" and "DataSpreadSheet" Worksheets look and replace values that are present in the Table.
Save the separate process workbook under another
Repeats the action on the other file in the folder.

This VBA proceeds the way I need, the only problem is that it takes so much time.
I have a bunch of files, over 100 to proceed regularly, and each file around 10-15 minutes to proceed, while the data for replacement is in range of B3:BB500 at most, with approximately 40% of cells in the range is actually filled with values.

The code is below, and do you have any suggestion on how to make it proceed faster? I have already disabled all calculations and updates while code is running.

The overall goal for the VBA is to translate Worksheets to another language using provided in Table translated strings arranged in columns for each language

I would appreciate help with rewriting the VBA.

```
    Dim fileCollection As Collection
Sub TraversePath(path As String)
    Dim currentPath As String, directory As Variant
    Dim dirCollection As Collection
    Set dirCollection = New Collection
    
    currentPath = Dir(path, vbDirectory)
    
    'Explore current directory
    Do Until currentPath = vbNullString
        Debug.Print currentPath
        If Left(currentPath, 1) <> "." And (GetAttr(path & currentPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            dirCollection.Add currentPath
        ElseIf Left(currentPath, 1) <> "." And (GetAttr(path & currentPath) And vbNormal) = vbNormal Then
            fileCollection.Add path & currentPath
        End If
        currentPath = Dir()
    Loop
    
    'Explore subsequent directories
    For Each directory In dirCollection
        Debug.Print "---SubDirectory: " & directory & "---"
        TraversePath path & directory
    Next directory
End Sub

Sub String_Autosubstitution()
'Logic: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook from a table

    Dim folderName As String, eApp As Excel.Application, fileName As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, currWs As Worksheet, currWb As Workbook
    Dim fDialog As Object: Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim Var, s As String, t As String, c As Range
    Dim newFolderFullName As String
    Dim newfileName As String
    Dim LangName As String
    Dim fndList As Integer
    Dim rplcList As Integer
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim LangColumn As Integer
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim MinutesElapsed As String
    'Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim rg As Range
    Dim Add As String
    Dim AddStart As String

'Timer count: Remember time when macro starts
StartTime = Timer

    Set currWb = ActiveWorkbook: Set currWs = ActiveSheet
    
    'Turn off automatic calculation for the VBA conteining Master Workbook
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'Select folder in which all files are stored
    fDialog.Title = "Select the folder with master files"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = Left(currWb.path, InStrRev(currWb.path, "\") - 1)
    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
      folderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    'Create a separate Excel process that is invisibile
    Set eApp = New Excel.Application:  eApp.Visible = True
   
    'Search for all files in folder [replace *.* with your pattern e.g. *.xlsx]
    Set fileCollection = New Collection
    TraversePath folderName & "\"
    
    For Each fileName In fileCollection
    
        'Update status bar to indicate progress
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & fileName

        'Open file
        Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName, ReadOnly:=True)

    'Turn off automatic calculation for the Slave Workbook
    eApp.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    'eApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    eApp.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
    eApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Create variable to point to your table
      Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LangLib").ListObjects("LangTable")
    
    'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
      Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
      myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
      
      'Set langauge columnt variable
      LangColumn = Application.Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Scripts").Range("S6")
      
    'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
      fndList = 1
      rplcList = LangColumn

    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = "Main" Or ws.Name = "DataSpreadsheet " Then
            
                'Define and set range on each sheet for execution
                Add = ws.Range("B1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
                AddStart = ws.Range("B1:" & Add).Address
                Set rg = ws.Range(AddStart)

                    'Loop through each item in Array lists (Array is the library of strigs from LangLib sheet)
                    For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
                        If myArray(rplcList, x) <> "" Then
                                
                                        rg.Cells.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
                                          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
                              End If
                                    On Error Resume Next
                      
                    Next x
                    
            End If
            
        Next ws
         'Sets name for file to be saved
        LangName = Application.Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("UI").Range("I37")
        newfileName = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 5) & LangName & ".xlsx"

    eApp.Calculation = xlAutomatic

        wb.SaveCopyAs fileName:=newfileName
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Debug.Print "Processed " & fileName  'Progress indication
              
    Next fileName
        
    eApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    'eApp.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    eApp.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = True

    eApp.Quit

    Set eApp = Nothing
    
    'Clear statusbar and notify of macro completion
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    

'Timer: Determines how many seconds code took to run
MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

'Notify user in seconds
MsgBox "Translation completed in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation
  
'MsgBox "Translation completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set eApp = New Excel.Application:  eApp.Visible = True` (I guess it should be `False` for invisibility).

Comment: I don't have much time to check the code carefully, but it looks like you're manipulation with data from within workbooks. Try copying data from worksheets to arrays and work with those arrays. When data get processed, you may copy arrays back to worksheets.

Comment: Right, I made the aApp visible to see what is actually happening to, I assume that is not effecting speed much since it has always been this slow even with hidden aApp.

Comment: I had been trying to work with array, but since I'm still learning VBA it came up a bit harder than I expected, that is the reason I am here, would appreciate help with array approach

Comment: How many workbooks are there involved? There is `CurrWb (ActiveWorkbook)` containing `CurreWs`, an `ActiveSheet` never used, `ThisWorkbook` containing the worksheet `LangLib`, `wb` containing the worksheets `Main` and `DataSpreadsheet`, and one or two `Application.ActiveWorkbooks` containing the worksheets `Scripts` and `UI`. It is clear what `ThisWorkbook` and `wb` are, but what about the rest? Please clarify which of the other workbooks are the same as the two cleared ones and what are the names of the ones not represented by the two.

Comment: How large is `LangTable`? Why are you transposing it, and doing the same thing for each opened workbook. That could be time-consuming. If you have to transpose it (you don't) then you should do it only once outside (before) the loop. Are the ranges always in columns `B:BB` and if so, is it possible to exclude some columns, e.g. the ones that contain formulas, or do all cells contain values? To which location (folder relative to `wb's` or `ThisWorkbook's` folder) will you be saving the new workbooks?

Comment: There are two workbooks open at the same time, the first one that is being launched from folder by user and which contains VBA and Table with values for substitution (UI,Scripts, LangLib Worksheets). The second Workbook is the one that is being translated (values in which should be substituted by values from the first woorkbook) contains (Main, DataSpreadSheet worksheets). Sorry for leaving CurreWs unmuted, it was created while trying different approaches to perform the task, it has no meaning in this code.

Comment: The **LangTable** is at least 1500 rows and 20 Columns. I might and probably will be bigger as time goes by and new lines added. i assume it will be close to 3000 rows.Im not sure about Transpose, It was giving a error if I set the array just as it is without transposing. Not sure about the **B:BB** range part, what do you mean ?They do contain formulas, which I belive should not be effected since there is no replacements for them in the LangTable library. The new workbook being saved in the same directory where original workbook is, but saved with adding a suffix to file name.

Comment: I'm asking about the workbooks because you reference the workbook containing this code with `ThisWorkbook` (you don't care what its name is). Use a variable for the other workbook similarly as you did: `Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName)` i.e. replace `Application.Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).` with `wb`. I was inquiring about the columns that you need to check because `Replace` may be faster on a smaller range, e.g. 3 columns vs 20 columns. Please clarify what `B3:BB500` in your post means and share which columns contain only values to be translated, maybe headers, too.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the details, will fix the wb referencing. regarding the B3:BB500, I cannot  set any other range, because it is where values are, and cells in that range may contain formulas, which can should be kept while replacing, but those cells with formulas are not defined and not a standard for every WS, so I cant set smaller range or column.

Answer (score 0):

*Will post as an answer, in order to show a code and visualization.*

You need a 2D array. This is the same worksheet (table). The difference is that you will have to use numbers when referring to the array's columns and rows (the same as for `Cells` property where you refer as `Cells(row_number, column_number)`).

Copy entire range that needs processing from the worksheet to a dynamic array. If you want the rows and column indices in the worksheet and in the array to be the consistent, start your range from the first cell (`A1`). This way, there will be no need in additional conversion from the worksheet cell indices and the array's ones because first row/column in the worksheet corresponds to the first row/column in the array. For example, `array(4, 5)` cell in the array refers to `Cells(4, 5)` cell in the worksheet.

Process the data in the array as required. Than, copy the data from the array back to the worksheet.

```
' Range that needs processing.
' I suggest starting the range from A1
' this way, the array row and column numbering
' will be the same as for the sheet
Dim rangeToCopy As Range
Set rangeToCopy = Sheet1.Range("A1:S20")
rangeToCopy.Select ' just to show range

' Copy data from sheet to 2D array.
' Note that is must be dynamic and of Variant type.
Dim arrayFromSheet() As Variant
arrayFromSheet = rangeToCopy

' Process needed part of array.
For r = Sheet1.Range("D6").Row To UBound(arrayFromSheet, 1)
  For c = Sheet1.Range("D6").Column To UBound(arrayFromSheet, 2)
    arrayFromSheet(r, c) = arrayFromSheet(r, c) + 1
  Next c
Next r

' Copy data from 2D array back to sheet.
rangeToCopy.Value = arrayFromSheet
```

[image: sheet range to array]

*Hope this helps.*

Comment: Thanks @ENIAC, trying to proceed, it returns Type Mismatch pointing to c in For c = ws.Range("D6").Column To UBound(arrayFromSheet, 2). Also, not quite sure what "D6" does here

Comment: @Vintage88, the `if` blocks under `' Process needed part of array.` in my example is just for example purpose. You should write your code there. `D6` in my example is the first cell of the range that needs processing.

Comment: @Vintage88, think it this way: a worksheet can be thought of as a table. 2D array can also be thought of as a table. Since both of them are tables, you can work with them the same (or at least, very similar) way.

Comment: @Vintage88, share some of the lines that don't work. Maybe I overlooked something.

Comment: Thanks @ENIAC, I think I understood the approach, though not sure why but the logic isnt working the same way as it had been  with direct proceeding of the cells on actual sheet. When I change rg.Cells.Replace to arrayFromSheet.Cells.Replace it starts returning Invalid Qualifier error from very first line of the VBA. Added updated code as an answer, refer to the code between as updated part '--------------new logic-------------

Comment: @Vintage88, `Range` is an object that contains `Cells` objects which have some methods. An `Array` is just a container that contains only some data. In your case, those data are just values (`String`, `Integer`, etc.) from a worksheet. That data don't have methods, thus, you cannot used `Cells` methods with `Array` values.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code using approach @ENIAC suggested, yet need to fix error.

```
Dim fileCollection As Collection
Sub TraversePath(path As String)
    Dim currentPath As String, directory As Variant
    Dim dirCollection As Collection
    Set dirCollection = New Collection
    
    currentPath = Dir(path, vbDirectory)
    
    'Explore current directory
    Do Until currentPath = vbNullString
        Debug.Print currentPath
        If Left(currentPath, 1) <> "." And (GetAttr(path & currentPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory Then
            dirCollection.Add currentPath
        ElseIf Left(currentPath, 1) <> "." And (GetAttr(path & currentPath) And vbNormal) = vbNormal Then
            fileCollection.Add path & currentPath
        End If
        currentPath = Dir()
    Loop
    
    'Explore subsequent directories
    For Each directory In dirCollection
        Debug.Print "---SubDirectory: " & directory & "---"
        TraversePath path & directory
    Next directory
End Sub

Sub String_Autosubstitution()
'Logic: Find & Replace a list of text/values throughout entire workbook from a table

    Dim folderName As String, eApp As Excel.Application, fileName As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, currWs As Worksheet, currWb As Workbook
    Dim fDialog As Object: Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim Var, s As String, t As String, c As Range
    Dim newFolderFullName As String
    Dim newfileName As String
    Dim LangName As String
    Dim fndList As Integer
    Dim rplcList As Integer
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim myArray As Variant
    Dim LangColumn As Integer
    Dim StartTime As Double
    Dim MinutesElapsed As String
    'Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim rangeToCopy As Range
    Dim Add As String
    Dim AddStart As String

'Timer count: Remember time when macro starts
StartTime = Timer

    Set currWb = ActiveWorkbook: Set currWs = ActiveSheet
    
    'Turn off automatic calculation for the VBA conteining Master Workbook
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    'Select folder in which all files are stored
    fDialog.Title = "Select the folder with master files"
    fDialog.InitialFileName = Left(currWb.path, InStrRev(currWb.path, "\") - 1)
    If fDialog.Show = -1 Then
      folderName = fDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If

    'Create a separate Excel process that is invisibile
    Set eApp = New Excel.Application:  eApp.Visible = True
   
    'Search for all files in folder [replace *.* with your pattern e.g. *.xlsx]
    Set fileCollection = New Collection
    TraversePath folderName & "\"
    
    For Each fileName In fileCollection
    
        'Update status bar to indicate progress
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing " & fileName

        'Open file
        Set wb = eApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName:=fileName, ReadOnly:=True)

    'Turn off automatic calculation for the Slave Workbook
    eApp.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    'eApp.ScreenUpdating = False
    eApp.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = False
    eApp.DisplayAlerts = False

    'Create variable to point to your table
      Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LangLib").ListObjects("LangTable")
    
    'Create an Array out of the Table's Data
      Set TempArray = tbl.DataBodyRange
      myArray = Application.Transpose(TempArray)
      
      'Set langauge columnt variable
      LangColumn = Application.Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("Scripts").Range("S6")
      
    'Designate Columns for Find/Replace data
      fndList = 1
      rplcList = LangColumn

    'Loop through each worksheet in ActiveWorkbook (skip sheet with table in it)
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            If ws.Name = "Main" Or ws.Name = "DataSpreadsheet " Then
            
                'Define and set range on each sheet for execution
                Add = ws.Range("B1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address
                AddStart = ws.Range("B1:" & Add).Address
                Set rangeToCopy = ws.Range(AddStart)
                
                '--------------new logic-------------
                
                
                
                rangeToCopy.Select
                
                Dim arrayFromSheet() As Variant
                arrayFromSheet = rangeToCopy


                    'Loop through each item in Array lists (Array is the library of strigs from LangLib sheet)
                    For x = LBound(myArray, 1) To UBound(myArray, 2)
                        If myArray(rplcList, x) <> "" Then
                        
                                        arrayFromSheet.Replace What:=myArray(fndList, x), Replacement:=myArray(rplcList, x), _
                                          LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
                                          SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

                                        ' Copy data from 2D array back to sheet.
                                          rangeToCopy.Value = arrayFromSheet
                                          
                                          
                                          
                '--------------new logic-------------
                
                
                
          
                                       End If
                                       
                                On Error Resume Next
                      
                    Next x
                    
            End If
            
        Next ws

        LangName = Application.Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name).Worksheets("UI").Range("I37")
        newfileName = Left(fileName, Len(fileName) - 5) & LangName & ".xlsx"

    eApp.Calculation = xlAutomatic

        wb.SaveCopyAs fileName:=newfileName
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Debug.Print "Processed " & fileName  'Progress indication
              
    Next fileName
        
    eApp.DisplayAlerts = True
    'eApp.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    eApp.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = True

    eApp.Quit

    Set eApp = Nothing
    
    'Clear statusbar and notify of macro completion
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
    Application.ErrorCheckingOptions.BackgroundChecking = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    

'Timer: Determines how many seconds code took to run
MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

'Notify user in seconds
MsgBox "Translation completed in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation
  
'MsgBox "Translation completed"

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd recommend provide the lines that throw an error (even better, the original line and modified one). That way, it may be much easier to find the root of the problem.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, actually the very first line with name of the sub being highlighted yellow, so this will not guide to actual error. But I think that **.Cells** method might be the problem here. That means the entire part of the logic should be rewritten? or there is a shorter way for this?

Comment: I'd say that objects' methods should be replaced with something else. For example, `arrayFromSheet.Replace` will not work, since [an array doesn't have that method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35205205/11827059).